# Ruby access hash within an array within a hash (and add new hash)

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I'm new to Ruby and still learning about hashes. I've tried looking here for other similar answers but wasn't able to find anything that completely answered my question.

**I have some data stored in a hash structure that I'm feeding into a script that updates a Neo4j database ( [so this data structure is important](http://www.sitepoint.com/crm-neo4j-rest/) ):**

```
    data = {
        a: [
        {
            label: 'Person',
            title: 'Manager',
            name: 'Mike Waldo'
        },
        {   
            label: 'Person',
            title: 'Developer',
            name: 'Jeff Smith',
        },
        ],

        b: [
        {   
            type: 'ABC',
            source: 'abcde',
            destination: ['Jeff Dudley', 'Mike Wells', 'Vanessa Jones']
        }
        ]
    }
```

**I've figured out how to return individual values:**

```
data.each{|x, y| puts y[0][:name]}
```

Returns: Mike Waldo

**Two questions:**

1) How do I return the 'labels', 'titles', and 'names' from array 'a: [ ]' only?

2) How do I add and save a new hash under array 'a: [ ]' but not ':b [ ]'?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You might want to check out the `neo4j` / `neo4j-core` gems which let you work with Neo4j at a higher level.  I'm one of the maintainers and I'm happy to help if you have any questions!

Comment: @BrianUnderwood Cool, I looked at it today and it looks like some great stuff! And thanks for the offer, I actually have one [question that's somewhat related.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30770914/how-do-i-create-a-neo4j-relationship-via-the-rails-console)

Comment: Awesome, looks like my colleague Chris beat me to it! ;)  I added a bit, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return values for specific key (:a)

```
data[:a]
# => [{:label=>"Person", :title=>"Manager", :name=>"Mike Waldo"}, {:label=>"Person", :title=>"Developer", :name=>"Jeff Smith"}]
```

And if you need to save value to :a Hash so you just use

```
data[:a] << {:label => "new label", :name => "new name", :titles => "new title"}
# => [{:label=>"Person", :title=>"Manager", :name=>"Mike Waldo"}, {:label=>"Person", :title=>"Developer", :name=>"Jeff Smith"}, {:label=>"new label", :name=>"new name", :titles=>"new title"}]
```

btw: your command (data.each{|x, y| puts y[0][:name]}) just return name value for fist hash if you need all names for all hashe you can use

```
data.each do |k, a|
  a.each do |h|
    puts h[:name]
  end
end
```

Comment: data[:a]! That was what I wasn't getting. Thanks for the help!